# Can't Access getcomposer.org Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, php, 17.04, composer

I Can't Access https://getcomposer.org (Through URL and Curl).
When I tried to access through URL its not loading the page.
And When I curl the same It shows Connection Timed Out.

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to getcomposer.org port 443: Connection timed out
```

I need to install composer in my Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

This worked fine for me. But when I tried to self update using

```
sudo composer self-update
```

It throws an error.

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]   
Command "self-update" is not defined.
```

I have already tried different solutions at Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu and GitHub, but nothing worked for me.
I didn't enabled any firewall and I'm not using any proxy. OpenSSL enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to access https://getcomposer.org with VPN from [vpnbook](https://www.vpnbook.com/)
and it works fine. For some people getcomposer.org will not accessible. because of there Lan May be Shared with multiple people. So If you can't access getcomposer.org, have a try with any VPN.

Thank You.